# Solving simultaneous systems of linear equations

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have several systems of linear equations in matrix form, and I would like to find the $\vec{x}$ that simultaneously solves them:
$$A_1\vec{x} = b_1$$
$$\vdots$$
$$A_n\vec{x} = b_n$$
Is there a quick/neat way to do this?  That is, something like: $$\text{LinearSolve}[A_1,b_1,\ldots,A_n,b_n]$$
If not, I will take a messy one.

Comment: Stack the matrices and right hand sides and do `LinearSolve[Astack,bstack]`. Both of these can be done with `Join`.

Comment: In other words, use `LinearSolve[Join[A1,...,An], Join[b1,...,bn]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has posted a "messy" solution yet, let me: if the matrices are in one list `alist = {a1,a2,...,an}` and the rhs' are in another, `blist = {b1,b2,...,bn}` then

```
Clear[x];
vars = x[#] & /@ Range[n];
vars /. Solve[Dot[#1, vars] == #2 & @@@ Transpose[{alist, blist}], vars]
```